# How to check if a macro is defined in MetaPost

Tags: metapost

Suppose one may or may not have a macro with a particular name defined in metapost, and depending on what's the case the behavior of the code needs to change in some way. Something like this:

```
vardef something (expr someargument) = someargument**2 enddef;
%vardef somethingElse (expr someargument) = someargument**3 enddef;

vardef doesItExist@# =
    % the code for the check goes here
enddef;

if doesItExist.something:
    fill fullcircle scaled 2cm withcolor red;
else:
    fill fullcircle scaled 2cm withcolor green;
fi; % should produce a red circle

if doesItExist.somethingElse:
    fill fullcircle scaled 1cm withcolor red;
else:
    fill fullcircle scaled 1cm withcolor green;
fi; % should produce a green circle
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You can use `known` or `unknown` to test whether a variable name has a value, but a macro will be expanded before it is tested.  If you look at the MFBook you will see that the usual technique is to do this sort of thing with numeric variables.  Eg `if unknown mode: mode := 1; fi`

Comment: With variables it's pretty straightforward, but with macros i currently can only get as much as a more or less predictable error message.